# Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_ShipStation_Integration Woocommerce issue

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, themes

In woocommerce I have the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot declare class WC_ShipStation_Integration, because the name is already in use in /home/dipdemon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-shipstation/includes/class-wc-shipstation-integration.php on line 0

Let me explain a little bit. We have a Woo Commerce bulk editing discount plugin that no longer will update or anything. It is not reflecting customer discounts in cart. So I installed a new one and am trying to get that one into play. But now nothing to do with Ship Station or WooCommerce will work. It is also saying something is wrong with Avada theme.

Now I cannot do ANYTHING at all on the site. I will paste the template overrides at the bottom. I am just not sure what to do now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Actually the whole site is down. Some of the WooCommerce plugins will not work or even update:

- Woo Commerce Extra Product Options
- Woo Commerce Ship Station Integration

> /home/dipdemon/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-tm-extra-product-options/templates/cart/cart-item-data.php,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/cart/cart.php version 2.3.8 is out of date. The core version is 3.5.0, 
>   Avada/woocommerce/checkout/form-pay.php version 2.5.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.4.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php version 2.3.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.3.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php version 2.2.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.2.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php version 2.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.3.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php version 2.5.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.5.5,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php version 2.5.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.4.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php version 2.6.3 is out of date. The core version is 3.5.1,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/product-thumbnails.php version 2.6.3 is out of date. The core version is 3.5.1,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/short-description.php version 1.6.4 is out of date. The core version is 3.3.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php version 2.0.0 is out of date. The core version is 3.0.0,  
>   Avada/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/description.php

**Also giving me these....**

> WooCommerce Bulk Pricing       by WP Lab – 1.8.2 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
>   WooCommerce Coupons Countdown       by itthinx – 2.5.0 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
>   WooCommerce PayPal Powered by Braintree Gateway     by WooCommerce – 2.2.0 – 2.2.1 is available
>   WooCommerce - ShipStation Integration       by WooThemes – 4.1.7 – 4.1.22 is available – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
>   WooCommerce TM Extra Product Options        by themecomplete – 4.4.1.1 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce
>   WooCommerce     by Automattic – 3.5.5
>   WooShip     by RightPress – 1.3.1 – Not tested with the active version of WooCommerce

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have a lot of experience with this as you can tell.

Comment: How can I make it more readable? Add some spaces?

Comment: The comment was mainly targeted at the previous revision that used quotes. Code blocks are generally more readable for repetitive line-sensitive messages.

Comment: Okay. I cannot even get onto the site now. I am trying to log into CPanel to fix it from there.

Comment: UPDATE : I do have the site back up now. Still having issues. If anyone knows anything about Avada Theme please let me know how to fix this. Any more info needed please let me know